# Django Rest Framework - OneToOne reverse relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom User model and the User Profile model.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    """Custom User authentication class to use email as username"""
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=255, unique=True,
                              error_messages={
                                  'unique': _(
                                          "A user is already registered with this email address"),
                              }, )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, default='0', null=False)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='', null=True)
```

I am trying to write a serializer that combines both these models are produces a nested JSON.

for example:

```js
{
  "email":"user@gmail.com",
  "is_active":true,
  "profile":
    {
      "emp_id":2,
      "department":2
    }
}
```

This is what I tried to do

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'emp_id', 'department')


class UserPairSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'is_active', 'profile')
```

But for some reason, there is neither the field `profile` in my response nor am I getting any errors. 
I tried following this docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

What is the issue and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships) implicitly refering to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), 'reverse' queries are done using the name of the Model, lowercased (in this case user.userprofile).

So you have two options:

Either you specify a custom `related_name` on the `user` field on the `UserProfile` model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
```

Or, you specify a `source` argument on your nested serializer (see [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)):

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'emp_id', 'department')


class UserPairSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(read_only=True, source='userprofile')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'is_active', 'profile')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. although the source takes a string. so it must be in quotes. I am not able to make an edit since its too little a change.

Comment: @KannanRavindran Sorry, was a bit too fast in typing down the answer!